# Animation connecting the first and the last point

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am new to matplotlib and I was playing with this library to plot data from a csv file. Without using the animation function the graph looks correct, but When I tried to use the animation, the graph connected the first and the last point. I looked stuff up, but I can't figure out how to solve this. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Below is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import csv

x = []
y = []

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):

    with open("example.txt", "r") as csvfile:
        plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for row in plots:
            x.append(int(row[0]))
            y.append(int(row[1]))

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(x,y)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot found using the animation]

Answer (score 0):

You append all the same points over and over again to the lists to plot. So say the csv file contains numbers `1,2,3` what you are doing is reading them in, appending them to the list, plotting them, then reading them in again and appending them etc.

So x contains in 
Step 1 : `1,2,3`
Step 2 : `1,2,3,1,2,3`
Step 3 : `1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3`

Hence from step 2 on there will be a connection between 3 and 1.

I don't know what the purpose of this animation is since animating all the same points is quite useless. So there is no straight forward solution, apart from not animating at all.

Comment: I am doing animation because I will be changing the values in my csv file and I want the graph to lively change whenever I change the vlaues in the csv file.

Comment: Will the values in the csv file be replace as it updates or will there be new values appended to it?